# Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload_200 FAILED

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, sentry

I have this error (below) occurring every time I want to build the release apk on my react native app.
I have already checked the auth token on the sentry.properties from here (https://sentry.io/settings/account/api/auth-tokens/) but the problem continue to work..

I have found a solution with
*./gradlew app:assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets*
but it doesn't solve the problem because when I start the apk it crashes every time.

Have you got some tips? Thank you

**error**: API request failed
caused by: sentry reported an error: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/var/lib/sentry/files/c5/25f3' (http status: 400)

Add --log-level=[info|debug] or export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=[info|debug] to see more output.
Please attach the full debug log to all bug reports.

API request failed

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload_200 FAILED
> caused by: sentry reported an error: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/var/lib/sentry/files/c5/25f3' (http status: 400)

Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload_200'.

> Process 'command '/Users/antoniomanitta/narvalo-frontend/node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have the same error...

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if it will help..

But in my case, i needed 3 steps.

1- I installed sentry-cli globaly on my pc

```
sudo npm install -g @sentry/cli --unsafe-perm
```

2- Than, I loggedin on terminal, using:

```
sentry-cli login
```

(following the process of login, and getting the necessary token)

3- Than, I updated my android/sentry.properties with the token generated

```
defaults.url=https://sentry.io/
defaults.org=my-organization
defaults.project=my-project
auth.token=token
```